# Android 'Element()' is not public in android renderscript element

Tags: android, element

I want to add a Header to an element, but I receive this error:

```
Android 'Element()' is not public in android renderscript element.
```

How can I resolve this?

Here is the code that is generating this error:

```
Element header = new Element().createElement("http://apache.org/headers",ComMsg);
```

Comment: Edited for clarity and language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RenderScript's `Element` class cannot be instantiated using the `new` keyword because all of its constructors have default (package private) visibility.

`Element` has 2 static factory methods which will create an `Element` instance for you:

```
Element myPixelElement = Element.createPixel(RenderScript rs, DataType dt, DataKind dk)
Element myVectorElement = Element.createVector(RenderScript rs, DataType dt, int size)
```

Depending on what you need, you can use one of these to create an `Element` instance.